# What is my next step?

Tags: installation, distributions

I have drupal core installed on my web host server and would like to install a panopoly distribution to it now. I have uploaded and extracted the tar.gz file to my docroot and can't seem to figure out how to install panopoly now. What should my next steps be? How do I install the install.php from panapoly? When I run the www.domain.com/install.php I get the message, "Drupal has already been installed"

Comment: Install profiles are used to install the site from the Drupal installer. There is no easy way to install panopoly. You would need to replicate what panopoly does by installing all of its dependencies on your site and running through any content management steps manually.

Answer (score 1):

If your website is not configured and you just has installed a pure drupal core without any modification , then you can forget about it and install a panopoly distribution instead, I mean you don't need a drupal installed before installing that distribution. Installation is pretty easy and straight forward in this case, you can read about it [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1651128).

In the other case if you have a website installed and running using drupal and you want to add panopoly to it , then the module itself has provided a [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1717728) about how to get it done. just follow the steps.